# How to use setInterval method in react for handling event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I am working on the Pomodoro Clock Project and I am wondering how I can make the **setInterval** method to work in react.

I have a code something like this :

```
class Pomodoro extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 25,
        };

        this.handleStartStop = this.handleStartStop.bind(this);
    }

    handleStartStop() {
        let counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
        this.state.count *= 60;
        function timer() {
            this.setState({
                count: (this.state.count -= 1),
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p id="timer-label"> Session</p>
                    <p id="time-left">{this.state.count}</p>
                </div>

                <button id="start_stop" onClick={this.handleStartStop}>
                    Start/Stop
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is , when I click the **Start/Stop button**  . the   {this.state.count} will decrement by 1  but I don't know how to use setInterval while handling events.

Every comment and suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: `function timer() {`  remember `this` here is not `this` of your Pomodoro class..  So one idea is just make your timer function the same way you did with `handleStartStop`, remembering the `bind`, your `this ` will then be correct.  Or even you want to keep `timer` as a sub-function, use the `that = this` construct.

Comment: Or you just use arrow functions. They have the `this` from the scope they are defined in.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I advise you setInterval is not accurate and will drift slowly to real time. It's better work with date time and use setinterval only to check the time passed from the stored date and bind all calculations to last retrieved time

Answer (score 3):

You can use an arrow function in order to have the correct `this` in your timer callback:

```
handleStartStop() {
    if (this.timer) {
        this.timer = clearInterval(this.timer);
        return null;
    }

    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState(prevState => 
        if (prevState.count === 0) {
            this.timer = clearInterval(this.timer);
            return null;
        }

        return {
            count: prevState.count - 1,
        };
    ), 1000);
}
```

Also note that when updating based on `state` you should always use the version of `setState()` that accepts a function where the first parameter is the previous state. This is because `setState()` is async and react may batch multiple calls to it. So you can't rely on the current `state` in the moment of calling `setState()`.

Also don't forget to clear the timer when the comonent unmounts:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Otherwise your callback will try to update the state after the component did already unmount which will lead to ugly warnings.

Comment: Thank you trixn for the example.